# Programmatically created EZAudioPlot does not draw

Tags: ios, swift2, ezaudio

I am playing audio file using EZAudioPlayer.
I want the soundwave to be drawn on EZAudioPlot.

I succeeded in doing this. 
However, when I create EZAudioPlot programmatically, the view shows but no soundwave is drawn.

Here is some of the code

```
var audioPlayer: EZAudioPlayer!
@IBOutlet weak var plot1: EZAudioPlot!
var plot1Flag:Bool = true

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let plotType: EZPlotType = EZPlotType(rawValue: 1)!;
    plot1?.plotType = plotType
    plot1?.shouldFill = true;
    plot1?.shouldMirror = true;


    plot2 = EZAudioPlot()
    plot2.plotType = plotType
    plot2.shouldFill = true;
    plot2.shouldMirror = true;
    plot2.frame = CGRectMake(10, 200, 200, 200)
    plot2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    plot2.color = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.view.addSubview(plot2)
}

@IBAction func playSound(sender: UIButton) {
    audioPlayer = EZAudioPlayer(URL: NSURL.fileURLWithPath(NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Alright", ofType: "wav")!), delegate: self)
    audioPlayer.play()
    plot1Flag = !plot1Flag
}

func audioPlayer(audioPlayer: EZAudioPlayer!, playedAudio buffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>>, withBufferSize bufferSize: UInt32, withNumberOfChannels numberOfChannels: UInt32, inAudioFile audioFile: EZAudioFile!) {
    if(plot1Flag){
        print("plot1")
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.plot1?.updateBuffer(buffer[0], withBufferSize: bufferSize);
        })
    }else{
        print("plot2")
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.plot2.updateBuffer(buffer[0], withBufferSize: bufferSize);
        })
    }

}
```

Can you tell me why the manually created plot2 doesn't draw?

Thank you for your insight!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for real time displays you need to add this line to your plot2 var

```
plot2.shouldOptimizeForRealtimePlot = false;
```

Hope it helps you :)

Here is the documentation:

> @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL shouldOptimizeForRealtimePlot;
>
> A BOOL that allows optimizing the audio plot’s drawing for real-time
>   displays. Since the update function may be updating the plot’s data
>   very quickly (over 60 frames per second) this property will throttle
>   the drawing calls to be 60 frames per second (or whatever the screen
>   rate is). Specifically, it disables implicit path change animations on
>   the waveformLayer and sets up a display link to render 60 fps (audio
>   updating the plot at 44.1 kHz causes it to re-render 86 fps - far
>   greater than what is needed for a visual display).